# Unable to find uploaded file inside Update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtEmpMaster" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:FileUpload ID="tPhoto" Height="23px" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btnImage" runat="server" Text="OK" 
onclick="Button1_Click" />

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tPhoto.HasFile)
    {
    …………………..;
    }
    else
    {
        …………………..;
    }
}
```

Here if condition is failing even after an image file is uploaded. No problem when using without `UpdatePanel`. `UpdatePanel` is also needed in current scenario. Any way I can have solution with `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Look at this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894132/auto-change-keyboard-language-using-javascript-not-work-without-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per link http://forums.asp.net/p/1105208/1689084.aspx

This problem is somewhat well documented, the update panel is listed as not working with certain controls.

File upload, and tree view being 2 of the biggies.

IN any case, one solution is available on code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/simpleajaxupload.asp

if you look around the forums and google, you can read more about the problem if your interested, but the code project solution should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Apply  this code line to solve your problem, to find the fileuploader into the update panel :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
}
```