# auto change keyboard language using javascript not work without IE

Tags: javascript, keyboard, onfocus, persian, farsi

i have a Java Script Code that can change Keyboard Language when focus on text box. but this code just work in IE and cant work correctly in Firefox or Opera
my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">
var farsi = true ;
var s = new Array(32,33,34,35,36,37,1548,1711,41,40,215,43,
              1608,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,
              57,58,1603,44,61,46,1567,64,1616,1584,125,
              1609,1615,1609,1604,1570,247,1600,1548,47,
              8217,1583,215,1563,1614,1569,1613,1601,
              8216,123,1611,1618,1573,126,1580,1688,
              1670,94,95,1662,1588,1584,1586,1610,1579,
              1576,1604,1575,1607,1578,1606,1605,1574,
              1583,1582,1581,1590,1602,1587,1601,1593,
              1585,1589,1591,1594,1592,60,124,62,1617);
//==============================================
    function change()
    {

   var KeyID =event.keyCode;
   if(KeyID >= 128)
 {
  alert("تغيير دهيد EN لطفا زبان صفحه کليد را به");
  event.keyCode=0;
  return false;
 }

 if(KeyID > 47 && KeyID < 58) return true;
 if(KeyID < 32)return true;
    if ( KeyID>32 && KeyID<128)  event.keyCode = s[KeyID-32] ;

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
> var KeyID =event.keyCode;
```

other browsers use *event.which*, so:

```
var KeyID = event.which || event.keyCode;
```

More generically you could do:

```
var keyProp = typeof event.which == 'number'? 'which' : 'keyCode';
```

then:

```
var keyCode = event[keyProp];
```

#### Edit

If you're still having issues, perhaps the [W3C DOM Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#legacy-key-attributes) will help. You may note that the *keyCode*, *which* and *charCode* properties of Event objects are **readonly**, though of course that section of the specification is informational, not normative, so browsers may or may not behave otherwise.